# How to call a stored procedure that has several types in C# on .NET Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, data-structures, datatable

I wrote a stored procedure that takes two types I created as parameters, called `Type1` and `Type2` :

```
CREATE TYPE Type1 AS TABLE
(
    Id [int] NULL,
    Value [float] NULL
)

CREATE TYPE Type2 AS TABLE
(
    Id [int] NULL,
    Name [varchar](20) NULL,
    Value [float] NULL
)

CREATE PROCEDURE [SP-Name]
    (@Id INT = 1,
     @UserName VARCHAR(500) = 'test',
     @Item1 Type1 READONLY,
     @Item2 Type2 READONLY)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM @Item1
END;
```

When I call this stored procedure in SQL Server itself, it runs without error, but I write the same code in C#, I get an error. What is the problem?

This is how I call this stored procedure in C#:

```
ENTITIES.SqlQuery<Result>($"EXEC [SP-Name] @Item1",
      new[] {
               new SqlParameter
               {
                   SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured,
                   TypeName = "Type1",
                   Value = listItems.ToDataTable(),//Get list Item from database and Convert to DATA-TABLE
                   ParameterName = "Item1"
               }}).ToList();

public class Result 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public static DataTable ToDataTable<T>(this List<T> items)
{
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable(typeof(T).Name);

        // Get all the properties
        PropertyInfo[] Props = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in Props)
        {
            // Defining type of data column gives proper data table 
            var type = (prop.PropertyType.IsGenericType && prop.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>) ? Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) : prop.PropertyType);

            // Setting column names as Property names
            dataTable.Columns.Add(prop.Name, type);
        }

        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            var values = new object[Props.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < Props.Length; i++)
            {
                // inserting property values to datatable rows
                values[i] = Props[i].GetValue(item, null);
            }

            dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
        }

        // put a breakpoint here and check datatable
        return dataTable;
    }
```

This is the error I get:

> Operand type clash: Item1 is incompatible with int

Comment: `EXEC [SP-Name] @Item1` would be a synonym of `EXEC [SP-Name] @Id = @Item1;` You have clearly defined `@Item1` in yoru C# code as `SqlDbType.Structured` and `@Id` is an `int`; so the error is telling you the problem. Presumably you want `EXEC [SP-Name] @Item1 = @Item1;`

Comment: Or, better yet, remove all the parameters from your procedure's definition apart from `@item1`, as none of them are used.

Comment: `@Item1` is of type Struct and is **User-Defined** must be of type Struct,See the code for **Sql Server** again

Comment: But you're passing `@item1` as the parameter for `@Id`, as I stated. See the code for SQL Server: `@Id INT = 1`. `int` <> `SqlDbType.Structured`

Comment: Which is the default state that if the user does not pass the ID value to SP 1, do you know Sql Server or do you want to comment in vain?

Comment: Yes, I know SQL Server very well, you clearly don't... You *think* that by passing a **variable** called `@item1` to a procedure it will be *inferred* that said parameter is for the parameter of the same name; your assumption is **wrong**.

Comment: DEclare variable as output.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?force_isolation=true&view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is you think that because you have a variable called `@Item1` that it will be inferred, by SQL Server, to be for the parameter `@Item1`, as they share the same name; this assumption is wrong.

When you omit the parameter that the variable is being passed to, the variables (or literals) are passed to the parameters based on ordinal position. You pass **one** value for your parameters, `@Item1`, which will be passed to your *first* parameter, `@Id`. This is why you get an error. `@Item1` is defined as a structured data type (`SqlDbType.Structured`), but `@Id` is an `int`; there are not the same data types, and you get an error.

If you want to omit parameters, be explicit on the parameters you are passing:

```cs
ENTITIES.SqlQuery<Result>($"EXEC dbo.[SP-Name] @Item1 = @Item1;",
```

Or, probably better, just remove all the other parameters from the procedure, as you don't use them:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[SP-Name] @Item1 Type1 READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * 
    FROM @Item1;
END;
```

Then you can use use `EXEC dbo.[SP-Name] @Item1;`.